# Why does the reaction of the primary alcohol cyclopentylmethanol with hydrogen bromide follow SN1 mechanism?

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism, alcohols

> **Example 2**: Identify all the products formed in the following reaction and indicate the major product.
>
> [image: Example 2]
>
> **Solution**: Three products will be formed in the given reaction as shown below:
>
> [image: Solution]

In this reaction the primary alcohol undergoes S<sub>N</sub>1 mechanism by forming a carbocation and then undergoing ring expansion, but primary alcohols prefer S<sub>N</sub>2 mechanism. So why is this primary alcohol undergoing S<sub>N</sub>1 mechanism?

Comment: The Sn1 mechanism should be considered relatively unreasonable here. You might consider a Sn1-like mechanism instead where ring expansion is the thing that displaces water, i.e., the C-C bond is the nucleophile.

Comment: But the carbocation is formed in Sn1 mechanism and ring expansion can only take place if carbocation is formed,also in this reaction the product formed by Sn1 mechamism is major product

Comment: "ring expansion can only take place if carbocation is formed" That is incorrect. The ring expansion could displace the leaving group.

Comment: The bottom line here is the the provide solution is wrong.

Comment: Is the given answer to the question regarding major product 1-bromo cyclohexane?

Comment: Actually i think what happens is Sn2 in beginning and then once that happened alchol slowly rearranges(you cannot stop the reaction , i mean formation of carbocation in acidic medium) , so final product same as due to Sn1 mechanism

Answer (score 4):

**It does not. The proposed mechanism is wrong.**

The conversion of cyclopentylmethanol to 1-bromo-1-methylcyclopentane is not reported *anywhere* in the literature. If you could somehow generate the primary carbocation, then one would expect a rapid 1,2-hydride shift to generate the more stable tertiary carbocation, giving rise to 1-bromo-1-methylcyclopentane.

The ring-expansion product could be rationalized by a concerted 1,2-alkyl shift displacing $\ce{OH2^+}$ without violating first-principles.