# Which mechanism should a reaction between the cyclopentylmethanol and the HBr should follow?

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism, alcohols, nucleophilic-substitution

I just thought that the reaction should follow $\mathrm{S_{N}2}$ mechanism this is because the alkyl halide is primary but the book says that the reaction will follow $\mathrm{S_{N}1}$ mechanism resulting in the formation of tertiary carbonation and a ring expansion product. Can anyone please explain the reason behind this ?

Comment: see http://www.chem.ucalgary.ca/courses/350/Carey5th/Ch04/ch4-5.html

Comment: @jezzo is but the alcohol mentionedis also a primary alcohol that's why I am confused because I also thought that the reaction should follow SN2 mechanism.

Answer (score 1):

It's a tricky example, but the $S_N1$ process is favored because the solvent is protic and the resulting 6-member ring is more stable than a 5-member ring.

If ring expansion weren't possible, I believe your intuition is correct that the $S_N2$ mechanism would dominate. See [this discussion](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/112785/why-primary-alcohol-follows-sn1-mechanism?rq=1). You're not alone!